# Slow math typing

Tags: math-mode, tools

I have been using LaTeX for quite some time, but I find the math writing to be a bit frustrating. It seems to take me a relatively long time to code-write long math expressions, and sometimes it's hard to see where `{` start and end. 
I am interested in writing as fast as possible.

Is code-typing each symbol really the fastest way?
Is there any good program (in the spirit of Word's MathType) that enables producing math expressions by button clicking, that you recommend?

Comment: Are you using a dedicated TeX editor?

Comment: And you really think that clicking buttons or choosing symbols from a menu is faster then just typing them on the keyboard?

Comment: I think it's faster. But maybe I'm not trained enough. Plus visual viewing of the formula is helpful I think, alongside the code itself. help visualizing complex formulae

Comment: vim with vim latex-suite has increased my speed significantly. vim has a learning curve, but it's worth learning if only for LaTeX (it can be used to edit any plain text)

Comment: @PineApple: I've converted your answer to a comment. Please register with the site, and you'll then automatically be able to comment on your own questions.

Comment: Don't forget that you can type in Math Type and export to LaTeX

Comment: [Math Type](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) is paid-for software...

Comment: @ThorstenDonig You can define your shortcuts which is way quicker than latex IMHO.

Answer (score 35):

As with learning any spoken language, getting the hang of expressing your math thoughts in TeX and LaTeX takes some time, and it requires quite a bit of practice to become truly proficient. And, as with learning any spoken language, the learning curve does flatten out considerably after a while, and writing math in LaTeX will seem to have become second nature. (Aside: I've been using TeX and LaTeX for more than 20 years.)

That said, I've found that the following "tricks" do help ease the learning process, and they tend to save you a lot of keystrokes in the process:

- Do study the manuals of the `amsmath` package; they're chock-full of good examples of interesting (to look at!) formulas. Really! The user guide of `amsmath` package shows how to use many great commands for typesetting equations and for entering matrices, to list just two examples of math-writing.
- Use a text editor that provides various syntax highlighting methods and highlights matching parentheses, brackets, and curly braces. If the editor gives you pull-down menus to choose and click math terms, all the better; however, you'll likely find yourself using this particular piece of support less and less.
- After you've entered a few formulas, take a look at the code and decide if there are any repeated stretches of code, such as second partials, integrals, and numerators and/or denominators of fractions. If these elements occur reasonably frequently, it's worth defining them as macros in your document's preamble and invoking them as needed in the main text. For example, if you have a lot of second partial derivatives, you may want to define a macro like

  ```latex
  \newcommand{\secondp}[3]{\ensuremath{\displaystyle%
      \frac{\partial^{2}\!{#1}}{\partial{#2}\,\partial{#3}}}}
  ```

  You'd invoke this macro as follows: `\secondp{f(x,y)}{x}{y}` or, if each argument consists of a single character, as `\secondp f x y`. (Putting braces around the `f`, `x`, and `y` won't hurt, of course, and it would likely make the code more readable as well.)

  What if you have a lot of own second partial expressions? Piece of cake -- just define another macro that takes *two* inputs:

  ```latex
  \newcommand{\ownsp}[2]{\ensuremath{\displaystyle%
       \frac{\partial^{2}\!{#1}}{\partial{#2}^2}}}
  ```

  - Two side benefits of using macros in this way are:

    1. they will save you a lot of typing over time and
    2. they will eliminate a major source of typos (and hence frustration arising from having to track down typos!).

    In the process of using macros frequently, you'll find that it becomes entirely natural to scrutinize formulas dispassionately, like an architectural critic who looks at the edifice as a whole, rather than like a laborer whose sole concern is how to place the next brick, or gargoyle, or whatever! By looking at the "big picture," so to say, you'll develop a facility to spot flaws in your edifice that you wouldn't be able to discover otherwise. E.g., is some part of the integrand "missing"? Should that be a minus sign instead of a plus sign?
- In addition, make a habit of scrutinizing your code for ways to separate, as much as possible, the content of your mathematical expressions from its appearance. What do I mean by this? A main feature of the entire structural philosophy of LaTeX is to separate content from appearance; while appearance depends (obviously!) on the content, it is also affected by decisions about how the content is formatted. While you may be comfortable with your formatting decisions, your thesis adviser, a journal editor, or co-authors may desire different styles for formatting various terms. If you've hard-coded (using lower-level LaTeX/TeX commands) all of the formatting commands, you're going to have to spend a lot of time re-formatting the content of your work to meet these new requirements.

  Take, for instance, the case of the cardinality of some set `A`. This is sometimes (often?) displayed as `|A|`. Now, some people like this formatting choice, but others prefer `||A||` (double vertical bars), or whatever. If you've defined a macro `\card` as follows: `\newcommand{\card}[1]{\ensuremath\left|#1\right|}` (implementing the former style) and have been using it consistently, your extra work should somebody demand a different style will be minimal. A side benefit of using the macro `\card` is that it emphasizes the logic of your code rather than the appearance -- never a bad thing, right?
- To give a different example: if you have lots of determinants of matrices, you're probably aware that they are required to be displayed as `|A|` in some journals but as `[A]` or `det(A)` in others, and in yet different styles in further journals. In order not to have to reformat all of your input to meet the formatting requirements of a particular journal, it's best to use a macro named `\det` each time your enter the determinant of a matrix. Actually, the macro `\det` is already defined, as a "math operator" that sets the letters "det" in upright (not italicized} text mode. If you find that you'd really prefer to have determinants typeset as `det(A)` -- with the matrix being the *argument* of the `\det` command -- or as `|A|` instead of the default `det A`, you could redefine the `\det` macro, say as follows:

  ```latex
  \let\origdet\det
  %% You should comment out one of the two next renewcommands
  \renewcommand{\det}[1]{\origdet\mathopen{}\left(#1\right)}   % to get "det(A)"
  \renewcommand{\det}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert} % to get "|A|"
  ```
- Finally, I strongly recommend that you collect all of your macros in a so-called LaTeX style file (named, say, `mymacros.sty`), and store this file somewhere in the LOCALTEXMF tree. That way, you can load the style file from your documents with the command `\usepackage{mymacros}`, and you'll always have easy access to your macros. And, if you ever want to redefine some of the macros, you'll only have to do so once.

  Another change you might want to make to your macros is (if you haven't already done so from the very beginning) is to add copious comments as to what they're supposed to achieve. (Of course, providing copious comments is considered a good programming habit everywhere, not just among LaTeX-ers.)

Happy TeXing!

Comment: excellent summary.  however, i'd warn against your suggestion to `\let\det\relax` and then `\newcommand{...}`; `\renewcommand` will be easier for some poor production editor to identify when a file submitted to a journal happens to redefine one of their "basic" set of commands, and throws a confusing error.

Comment: @barbara beeton: I fully agree with you. I was actually having some second thoughts about that example myself as I was writing it, and I was thinking about stating it instead with a `\renewcommand` macro. However, I won't edit the text of the answer now, or else your follow-up comment won't make much sense. :-)

Comment: Actually, for that example you'd want to redefine `\det` in all cases since it would be hard to redefine `\det` so that `\det A` produced `|A|`.  One solution would be: `\let\origdet=\det \renewcommand{\det}[1]{\origdet(#1)}`.  Then you could do `\renewcommand{\det}[1]{\left\lvert #1\right\rvert}` if required.

Comment: (By the way, you shouldn't let worrying about comments prevent you from editing your answer to make it better.  You can always say, "(Thanks to Barbara Beeton for pointing this out in the comments)".  Then it's clear that Barbara's comment refers to an earlier version and you've corrected your answer accordingly.  Indeed, I'd encourage you to do this.)

Comment: @Andrew: Great point! I'll go ahead and make the change.

Comment: In your use of `\secondp`, you need to remove the external braces, otherwise the three arguments are taken as only one single argument.

Comment: Good catch! I've fixed the problem. I've also added the \displaystyle command to the macro's definition and dispensed with a comment about the need for curly braces around the macro's parameters.

Comment: @Mico: you're also missing a pair of braces after your two `\ensuremath`. Spacing-wise, it's a bit dangerous to put a `\!` as one may want to use `\secondp{\mathbf{H}}{x}{y}` and then the 2 and the H telescope. Also, normally, you don't put a thin space before a `\partial`, as it serves no purpose.

Comment: @Mico: you should also add a `\mathopen{}` between `\origdet` and `\left` to avoid a spurious space: `\renewcommand{\det}[1]{\origdet\mathopen{}\left(#1\right)}`.

Comment: Incidentally, I hope you're taking all these comments as a sign that this is a Great Answer and others are just being helpful with the polishing!

Comment: @Philippe: Thanks for pointing out the missing braces following the `\ensuremath` commands, for pointing out a potential problem caused by the negative thinspace should the `\partial^2` be followed by a character in upright rather than in slanted shape, and for suggesting the addition of the `\mathopen{}` instruction following the `\origdet` command. I've edited my code accordingly. Finally, on the insertion of a thinspace between the two partials in the denominator: I'm pretty sure that this straight out of the TeXBook (ch. 18?), so I'll leave it in for now. :-)

Comment: +1 for using a good editor which highlights matching braces.

Comment: @Mico: the TeXbook doesn't talk about thin spaces before `\partial` (and only gives examples with `\partial^2x`, not `\partial x\partial y`). The thin space is only mentioned for the differential `d` (for which it avoids ambiguity by differentiating it from a normal letter; as `\partial` is already itself special, the same reasoning doesn't apply). In books about Math typography, Swanson (AMS) and Chaundy (Oxford) don't mention special spacing for `\partial` (but do for `d`), while Wick (page 37) and Lansburgh (page 289, in Swedish) both show an example with a thin space before `\partial`.

Comment: @Philippe Goutet: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. On the desirability of inserting a `\thinspace` between two consecutive (though not, I admit, explicitly *partial*  ) differentials, I appeal to pp. 168f. of the TeXBook as well as to p. 40 of Ellen Swanson, *Mathematics into Type*, 1991/1999, American Math. Soc.

Comment: @LoopSpace - You wrote, more than 8 years ago by now, "I hope you're taking all these comments as a sign that this is a Great Answer". Back then, I had only recently joined this site, and I still felt very new and self-conscious about posting *any* answers. I'm pretty sure that this was the longest answer I had posted up until then. I distinctly remember how encouraged I felt by your kind words. A belated *Thank You* shout-out to you is in order! (PS The occasion for this comment is that I just got notified about another upvote -- the 27th in all!)

Comment: @Mico And thank you for that thank you!  Given that your reputation here is now about triple mine then I feel honoured to have helped you feel more relaxed about posting here.

Comment: `physics` package has some nice shortcuts that you might want to use

Comment: @Damitr - Thanks. The list of things that the `physics` package can for math typesetting, and physical math typesetting, is very long. Please feel free to post a *new* answer to cover the benefits of employing the `physics` package. Incidentally, the fact that I mentioned the `amsmath` package twice in my answer, but didn't really mention any other packages that also simplify the typesetting of mathematical expressions, is hopefully not understood as an attempt to downplay the benefits of those other packages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have added a separate answer

Answer (score 13):

I find it quite natural to code math in LaTeX. Having said that, part of this is because I define macros to make it faster. Without being able to express myself with the following macros,

- `\x` to produce `\times` ( × ) and `\ox` to produce `\otimes` ( ⊗ )
- `\C` to produce `\mathbb C` ( ℂ ) and `\Z` to produce `\mathbb Z` ( ℤ )
- `M\trans` to produce `M^\top` ( M<sup>⊤</sup> ) and `M\herm` to produce `M^\dagger` ( M<sup>†</sup> )
- `\ens{1,2,3}` to produce `\left\{ 1, 2, 3 \right\}` ( {1,2,3} )
- `\norm{A}` to produce `\left\| A \right\|` ( || A || )
- `\ket{x}` to produce `\left| x \right\rangle` ( |*x*⟩ )

and their like, I would take a lot longer to express myself mathematically in LaTeX. Defining macros such as this will make it more difficult to collaborate on a single file, however, unless you and your co-authors agree on the same set of macros.

Answer (score 6):

The vim-latex package for vim and auctex for emacs have shortcuts like `` `a `` expands to `\alpha`, `` `* `` expands to `\times`, etc. These shortcuts greatly speed up math typesetting. When using the luatex engine (either lualatex or context), I change these shortcuts so that `` `a `` produces `α` and so on. This makes it much easier to edit math expressions later on.

Answer (score 5):

I found the `physics` package quite helpful in writing maths code. The package though primarily making life simpler for physicists, nonetheless can be useful for general mathematical writing as well.

`\qty{}`

`\abs{}` for absolute values

`\norm{}` for norm of the values

plus commutators and poisson brackets.

For me, the part where `physics` package really shines is handling of vector notation, derivatives, braket notations and matrices.

For example `\vb{A}` will produce an upright bold vector A `\vb*{A}` will produce a slant bold vector.

`\grad` `\div` and `\curl` and `\laplacian` are predefined

[image]

Also it has a neat command for text within the equation with space around it:
`\qq{text}` with white space around it, it makes writing text in equations much easier. Also there are several predefined commonly used phrases in equations such as

`\qif,\qthen, \qelse, \qotherwise, \qunless, \qgiven, \qusing, \qassume, \qsince, \qlet, \qfor, \qall, \qeven, \qodd, \qinteger, \qand, \qor, \qas, \qin`

[image]

Writing derivatives is much simplified:

`\dd x` will create dx with upright d and math mode x, this provides easy way to write differentials.

Similarly for derivative `\dv{x}` will produce d/dx with upright d and math x.

`\dv[n]{f}{x}` will produce d^n f/ dx^n

`\pdv{x}` will produce partial derivatives and so on.

[image]

`\braket{a}{b}` will produce ⟨a|b⟩.

[image]
[image]

Similarly there are quite a few shortcuts for martices:

[image: matrices]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to type LaTeX insanely fast in any text editor (included the math.stackexchange site) under a Windows operating system (unfortunately I dont find a way to do the same in Linux distributions). It rely on a free software named [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/): this is a software that give you the possibility to write strong custom scripts to simplify repetitive actions.

What I did was just define a list of *hotstrings*: a hotstring is a typed string that is replaced immediately by another custom string, basically a hotstring is something like

```
::str1::str2
```

This means that the string `str1` will be immediately replaced by the string `str2` after you type it, therefore you can abbreviate the typing of any TeX command or macro to just two or three strokes.

As an example [there](https://github.com/Masacroso/autohotkey) is the actual script that I use to type LaTeX (it is carefully designed to enhance immensely the typing of LaTeX but it is designed to use with an spanish keyboard distribution, however reading the script you can adapt it easily to your preferences).

UPDATE: now I'm using [espanso](https://espanso.org/) instead of autohotkey. It can be used in mac, linux and windows systems (and currently I just use a linux distribution).

Comment: You wrote about autohotkey: "this is a software that give you the possibility to write strong custom scripts to simplify repetitive actions". It would be very helpful if you showed *how* this claim addresses the OP's issue, which was about *math typesetting*.